# Finding all prime powers of the form $\frac{n(n-1)}{10}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

I was trying to come up with a problem where the solutions would be the numbers 5, 6, 10 and 11. It seems like "finding all integers n, where $\frac{n(n-1)}{10}$ is a prime power", is a good attempt, as there are at least no other solutions for n < 1.000.000 (tested with python).

However, I didn't manage to prove that there are no other numbers that match this criteria, so I wonder whether there are none, or whether it's just that prime powers are quite rare, and there could be very large numbers still matching my criteria. Can anyone help me out there?

Comment: Sorry, I meant n(n-1). I edited my question now.

Comment: Hint: $n$ and $n-1$ are relatively prime.

Comment: The only cases where $n(n-1)/10$ is an integer is $n\equiv 0,1,5,6\pmod {10}.$ In each of those cases, we can factor $n(n-1)/10$ into relatively prime integers, so one of those must be $1.$

Comment: Yeah I think I got it now, thanks for the hint!

Comment: For example, when $n\equiv 5\pmod{10},$ $n(n-1)/10=\frac n5\cdot\frac{n-1}2.$

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your approach. The way I imagined it now, I have the formula $10*p^x=n(n-1)$. The prime factorization of both must therefore be $2*5*p^x$. As $n$ and $n-1$ are relatively prime, only one of them can have p as prime factor. So either $n$ or $n-1$ (the one p does not divide) can only consist of dividers of 10, which leaves only our limited options.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since $n - 1$ and $n$ are coprime, at least one of them must be a factor of $10$, hence $n \leq 11$.